# Hatov vehametiv on a kos shel bracha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, bentching, grapes-wine

Someone intends to bentsh on a kos, and a new wine is brought to the table at that time.

For a person who generally recites HaTov v'HaMetiv, could they do so on the kos shel bracha, or does Birkas HaMazon reset the wine count? If so, when exactly would they say it--before hagafen?

Comment: You could ask the same question about the 2nd and 4th cups on Pesach, and the answer or at least the reason for the answer would have to be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magen Avraham (175 sk 0) rules that the fourth blessing of the Bentching (that of HaTov VeHaMeitiv) exempts the new wine in the cup used for Bentching from another HaTov VeHaMeitiv. Mishna Berura (ibid. sk 2) rules this way as well.